# How to order by Date in Sql Server GROUP BY formatted date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as follows:

```
Table: student_test_records

Student    TestDate                    Result
-------    ------------------          -------
A          2015-01-26 17:28:11         Pass
B          2015-01-24 17:28:11         Fail
C          2015-01-26 17:28:11         Pass
D          2015-01-26 17:28:11         Fail
E          2014-05-23 17:28:11         Pass
F          2013-06-23 17:28:11         Pass
G          2014-05-23 17:28:11         Fail
```

I am attempting to write a query in SQL Server to display the number of passed/failed results per day in the following format:

```
FormattedDate          Result  Count
-----------            ------  ----- 
May-23-2013            Pass    1
May-23-2014            Fail    1
May-23-2014            Pass    1
Jan-24-2015            Fail    1
Jan-26-2015            Fail    1
Jan-26-2015            Pass    2
```

The following is the query I attempted:

```
SELECT FORMAT(TestDate, 'MMM-dd-yyyy') as FormattedDate, Result, Count
FROM student_test_records  
GROUP BY FORMAT(TestDate, 'MMM-dd-yyyy'), Result 
order BY FORMAT(TestDate, 'MMM-dd-yyyy');
```

The result set is correct, but the ordering comes by formatted date string (month-day-year alphabetically). How do I order the result on actual date (TestDate)? In MySQL, I could have done `ORDER BY TestDate` instead of the last line in the above query.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT(cast(TestDate as date), 'MMM-dd-yyyy') as FormattedDate,
  Result,
  Count(*) as Count
FROM student_test_records  
GROUP BY cast(TestDate as date), Result 
ORDER BY cast(TestDate as date);
```

Comment: Wow, that works! Could you please explain why the cast is needed?

Comment: because you need to remove the timestamp, sqlserver can't recognize that format as a date. Would have been different if you had used convert/cast instead

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much already there with it

```
SELECT FORMAT(TestDate, 'MMM-dd-yyyy') as FormattedDate, Result, Count(*)
FROM student_test_records  
GROUP BY TestDate, Result 
ORDER BY TestDate;
```

Comment: I had tried it. I need to group by MMM-dd-yyyy because I need to eliminate hours, min, secs etc. But if I put that, I cannot order by the TestDate. I would be forced  to order by the formatted date, which orders as a string instead of date.

Comment: This will result in  grouping the data gain based on the date.