# Get running total of users for each year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to calculate the total number of users that uses my application each year. both new and returning users.

I created this script below but it only shows total number of users for only 1 year. I would like to see the total for the years before (<= 2010-12-31). also note the years before can be more that 3.

```
SELECT '2010-12-31' as date, count(*) as year
        FROM users AS c 
        WHERE FORMAT(c.first_joined, 'yyyyMMdd') <= '2010-12-31 ' 
        AND status = 'ACTIVE'
```

first_joined: this is the date the user first entered the system
total: this is the total of both new and returning users

results:

| date | total |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-12-31 | 8,617 |

Expected results will providing a running total of previous and current years:

| date | total |
| --- | --- |
| 2007-12-31 *(1,000 joined in 2007)* | 1,000 |
| 2008-12-31 *(200 joined in 2008)* | 1,200 |
| 2009-12-31 *(1,000 joined in 2009)* | 2,200 |
| 2010-12-31 *(6,417 joined in 2010)* | 8,617 |

Comment: You need to use GROUP BY on the first_joined column, formatted to just return the year. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166998/how-to-order-by-date-in-sql-server-group-by-formatted-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operator with [DATEPART()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp) function and then use [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/#:%7E:text=A%20window%20function%20performs%20a,done%20with%20an%20aggregate%20function.) to get the data you wants.

see the following code as example:

```
WITH yearly_new_data AS (
SELECT
     DATEPART(year,c.first_joined) as dt, 
     count(*) as total
FROM users AS c 
WHERE c.first_joined < CAST('20110101' AS DATE)
      AND status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY
     DATEPART(year,c.first_joined)
)
SELECT
    dt,
    SUM(TOTAL) OVER (order by dt) AS total
FROM
    yearly_new_data
```

Comment: this only returns the amount of new users in system. I'd like all users both new and returning

Comment: Hi @java-life-love, we don't have access to the table schema. In your problem description, you only mentioned first_joined column. What is the column we can tell whether it is a returning customer.

Comment: first_joined is the date the user joined the system. so this column can be used to calculate both new and returning users based on the date they joined the system

Comment: @java-life-love, are you saying if a user joined on '2012-06-01', then we can confidently say that user is a returning customer in 2013, 2014, 2015,..... ?

Comment: @junjie yes that is the idea

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes the total up to end of 2010. as I displayed in the expected results for  year: 2008-12-31 the total for both new and returning users is the 1200

Comment: Hi @java-life-love, I have updated the query to add a window function to get the result you want.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to apply `FORMAT()` of all things to the column side of a comparison. See [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but), [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7144/sql-date-format-comparison-sql-format-sql-convert/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7145/sql-date-format-comparison-computed-column-materialized-column/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), and [this](https://sqlpete.wordpress.com/2020/05/14/dont-use-functions-on-the-left-hand-side-of-a-condition-in-sql/).

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand. Good point. update the query to cast (AS date) instead of formatting.

Comment: Great, but if `first_joined` is date time, your query will miss users who joined on, say, 12/31 at noon. Always better to do `< start of next boundary`, e.g. `< '20110101'`.

Comment: Right, updated accoringly, @AaronBertrand.

Comment: :-) needs to be `<` not `<=` - [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Abfm-fNB).

Comment: updated to use < with 20110101

Answer (score 1):

> `WHERE FORMAT(c.first_joined, 'yyyyMMdd') <= '2010-12-31 '`

Oh boy, no, `FORMAT()` outputs a string, which is no way to compare dates, and in a terribly inefficient way to boot. Also `yyyy-MM-dd` is an unsafe format for date literals (some languages will interpret that as `yyyy-dd-MM`).

We want (now that we sussed out that this is *actually* a disguised running total problem):

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT [date]  = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(first_joined),12,31),
         [total] = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.users AS u
  WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
  AND first_joined < '20110101'
  GROUP BY YEAR(first_joined)
)
SELECT [date], total = SUM(total) OVER(ORDER BY [date])
  FROM src ORDER BY [date];
```

See some date handling tips in [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).